# DOM events (for 3D objects using three.js; raycaster) not being detected on a secondary javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, code-splitting

I made a personal website using Vite, which just does all the work for you when it is time to bundle it, javascript, html, and css. I used the js library called three.js that is just four 3d objects that detects mouse clicks and mouse hovering.

I then tried to bundle my work and it almost worked, except the three.js portion of it seemed to be missing. I checked the logs for how it was bundled and there was a message that even though 4 modules were successfully transformed, there was something named

```
dist/assets/vendor.a8662437.js
```

that returned the message

```
 504.39kb / brotli: skipped (large chunk)

(!) Some chunks are larger than 500kb after minification. Consider:
- Using dynamic import() to code-split the application
- Use build.rollupOptions.output.manualChunks to improve chunking: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputmanualchunks
- Adjust chunk size limit for this warning via build.chunkSizeWarningLimit.
```

So I figured that even though my project was basic, it did consist of 2 functions, one for mousemove events and one for mouseclick events. After more and more research I am pretty confident I did all the steps but my problem is that the original javascript file has the mouseclick function and when I click on the objects, it works as expected, but when I hover the mouse over the objects, nothing happens.

I made sure to import the three.js library into that javascript file as I do in my main js file. As I would save the file I would receive errors and one by one I fixed them since the errors were pretty clear that I was missing a declaration here or that something was already declared. I also put the script tag in the html body like the main javascript file. Is there something else I have to do? I will provide the relevant parts of the file...

I started with an index.html file and a main.js file. I created a secondary js file named hover.js. You can see I added the script tag for it in the html file.

here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="HRicon.svg" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Hyperrocket BSC</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>screen.orientation.lock('landscape');</script>
    <canvas id="bg">
    <script src='https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/tweenjs.min.js'></script>
    <script type="module" src="/hover.js"></script>// I ADDED THE SCRIPT TAG HERE <-----
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.7.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
    </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is my main.js file with the mouseclick function which DOES work

```
import './style.css'
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.117.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import TWEEN from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tweenjs/tween.js@18.5.0/dist/tween.esm.js';

// THESE WERE JUST ADDED TO TRY TO MAKE THE SECONDARY JAVASCRIPT FILE WORK

import {onMouseMove} from './hover.js'
export {scene, camera};
export {minicylinder1, minicylinder2, minicylinder3, minicylinder4};

// THESE WERE JUST ADDED TO TRY TO MAKE THE SECONDARY JAVASCRIPT FILE WORK

//BASIC SCENE SETUP
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

//LIGHTS (POINT AND AMBIENT)
const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xB7B7B7);
pointLight.position.set(-25, 0, 30);
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xB7B7B7);
scene.add(pointLight, ambientLight);

//RESIZE WINDOW
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    render();
}, false);

//ORBIT CONTROLS
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.minDistance = 5;
controls.maxDistance = 70;
controls.enablePan = false;
controls.enableRotate = false;
controls.enableZoom = false;
controls.target.set(0,0,-1);
camera.position.setZ(28);
var origPos = new THREE.Vector3().copy(camera.position);

// *******************************************************************//
//                              3D OBJECTS                            //
//                                                                    //
//********************************************************************//


const minigeometry1 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(5, 5, 0.5, 50);
const minimaterial1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();
const minicylinder1 = new THREE.Mesh(minigeometry1, minimaterial1);
minicylinder1.name = 'minicylinder1';
minicylinder1.position.x = -17.5;
minicylinder1.rotation.z = Math.PI / 2;
minicylinder1.rotation.y = Math.PI / 2;
scene.add(minicylinder1);

const minigeometry2 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(5, 5, 0.5, 50);
const minimaterial2 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial();
const minicylinder2 = new THREE.Mesh(minigeometry2, minimaterial2);
minicylinder2.name = 'minicylinder2';
minicylinder2.position.y = 8.5;
minicylinder2.rotation.z = Math.PI / 2;
minicylinder2.rotation.y = Math.PI / 2;
scene.add(minicylinder2);
```

This section is just stuff for the tween camera movement I trigger on mouseclicks. this all works, feel free to skip this block.

```
//CAMERA MOVEMENT FUNCTION TOWARD EACH COIN//
function tweenCamera(finalPosition, tweenSpeed) {
    let initialPosition = new THREE.Vector3(camera.position.x, camera.position.y, camera.position.z);
    new TWEEN.Tween(initialPosition)
    .to(finalPosition, tweenSpeed)
    .onUpdate(() => {
        camera.position.set(initialPosition.x, initialPosition.y, initialPosition.z);
    })
    //.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.Out)
    .start();
}

//TWEENS THE CAMERA BACK TO CENTER//

//WHERE THE CAMERA IS CURRENTLY LOOKING, I THINK
let currentTarget = new THREE.Vector3();
currentTarget.set(controls.target.x, controls.target.y, controls.target.z);

let originTarget =  new THREE.Vector3();
originTarget.set(0,0,0);

//TELLS CAMERA TO ORIENT TOWARD SPECIFIED OBJECT (target controls = camera orientation?)
let cylinderTarget = new THREE.Vector3();
cylinderTarget.set(0, 0, -10);
let minicylinder1Target = new THREE.Vector3();
minicylinder1Target.set(-30, minicylinder1.position.y, minicylinder1.position.z);
let minicylinder2Target = new THREE.Vector3();
minicylinder2Target.set(minicylinder2.position.x, 16, minicylinder2.position.z);
```

This is the mouse click function that has worked and still works perfectly fine...

```
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

let coin1Clicked = false;
let coin2Clicked = false;
let coin3Clicked = false;
let coin4Clicked = false;

function onClick(event) {
    //Normalized mouse coordinates (-1, +1)
    mouse.x = (event.offsetX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
    
    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
    
    if ((getIndexInIntersectsArray(scene.getObjectByName('bhText'), intersects) > -1)) {
        window.open(scene.getObjectByName('bhText').userData.URL);
    }
    
    //IF WE CLICK ON AN OBJECT, WE WILL ZOOM INTO IT
    if ((getIndexInIntersectsArray(minicylinder1, intersects) > -1) && (!coin1Clicked)) {
        tl.to(".slide1", {delay: 2.1,duration: 0.7, clipPath: 'polygon(100% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%)'});

        coin1Clicked = true;

        //CODE THAT ACHIEVES MY SLIGHT ROTATION THAT I FOUND ON STACKOVERFLOW
        var start = {}
        start.y = 0;
        var targ = {};
        targ.y = 0;
        function rot(s,t) {
            start["y"] = s;
            targ["y"] = t;
        }  
        rot(1.5*Math.PI/2, 4.3*Math.PI);
        const spun1 = new TWEEN.Tween(start).to(targ, 2500).onUpdate(function() {minicylinder1.rotation.y = start.y}).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quintic.Out);
        spun1.start();

        window.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);

        new TWEEN.Tween(currentTarget)
            .to(minicylinder1Target, 2500)
            .onUpdate(function() {
                controls.target = currentTarget; 
            })
            .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quartic.InOut)
            .start()
        //RESTRICT CAMERA ROTATION AND ZOOM OUT
        tweenCamera(new THREE.Vector3(-30, minicylinder1.position.y, 7), 2500)

        return coin1Clicked;
    } else if ((getIndexInIntersectsArray(minicylinder1, intersects) > -1) && (coin1Clicked)) {
        tl.to(".slide1", {duration: 0.7, clipPath: 'polygon(100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%)'});

        //CODE THAT ACHIEVES MY SLIGHT ROTATION THAT I FOUND ON STACKOVERFLOW
        var start = {}
        start.y = 0;
        var targ = {};
        targ.y = 0;
        function rot(s,t) {
            start["y"] = s;
            targ["y"] = t;
        }  
        rot(4.3*Math.PI, 4.5*Math.PI);
        const spun1 = new TWEEN.Tween(start).to(targ, 2500).onUpdate(function() {minicylinder1.rotation.y = start.y}).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quintic.Out);
        spun1.start();

        //TWEEN TO ORIENT CAMERA TOWARDS ORIGIN
        new TWEEN.Tween(currentTarget)
            .to(cylinderTarget, 2500)
            .onUpdate(function() {
                controls.target = currentTarget; 
            })
            .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quartic.InOut)
            .start()
        coin1Clicked = false;

        tweenCamera(origPos, 2500) //FOR THE TEXT ELEMENTS ALSO

        window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);

        return coin1Clicked;
    } else if ((getIndexInIntersectsArray(minicylinder2, intersects) > -1) && !coin2Clicked) {
        tl.to(".slide2", {delay: 2.1,duration: 0.7, clipPath: 'polygon(0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%)'});

        coin2Clicked = true;

        var start = {}
        start.y = 0;
        var targ = {};
        targ.y = 0;
        function rot(s,t) {
            start["y"] = s;
            targ["y"] = t;
        }  
        rot(1.5*Math.PI/2, 4.5*Math.PI);
        const spun2 = new TWEEN.Tween(start).to(targ, 2500).onUpdate(function() {minicylinder2.rotation.y = start.y}).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quintic.Out);
        spun2.start();

        new TWEEN.Tween(currentTarget)
            .to(minicylinder2Target, 2500)
            .onUpdate(function() {
                controls.target = currentTarget; 
            })
            .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quartic.InOut)
            .start()
        tweenCamera(new THREE.Vector3(minicylinder2.position.x, 16, 7), 2500)

        window.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);

        return coin2Clicked;
    } else if ((getIndexInIntersectsArray(minicylinder2, intersects) > -1) && (coin2Clicked)) {
        tl.to(".slide2", {duration: 0.7, clipPath: 'polygon(0% 100%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%)'});

        new TWEEN.Tween(currentTarget)
        .to(cylinderTarget, 2500)
        .onUpdate(function() {
            controls.target = currentTarget; 
        })
        .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quartic.InOut)
        .start()
        
        coin2Clicked = false;
        tweenCamera(origPos, 2500);

        window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);

        return coin2Clicked;
    }
}
function getIndexInIntersectsArray(elem, array) {
    var ind = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].object.name == elem.name) {
            ind = i;
        }
    }
    return ind;
}
    
window.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    onClick(event);
})

window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    
var animate = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    particlesMesh.rotation.y -= 0.00035;
    controls.update();
    render();
    TWEEN.update();        
};
    
function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
    
animate();
```

This here is the secondary file, with the javascript function that does not trigger the action inside the blocks of the if statement.

```
export {onMouseMove};
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {scene, camera } from './main.js';
import { minicylinder1, minicylinder2 } from './main.js';
import TWEEN from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tweenjs/tween.js@18.5.0/dist/tween.esm.js';

// *******************************************************************//
//                            MOUSE HOVER                             //
//                                                                    //
//********************************************************************//
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);

let coin1Hover = false;
let coin2Hover = false;

function onMouseMove(event) {
    mouse.x = (event.offsetX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
    
    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
    
    if ((getIndexInIntersectsArray(minicylinder1, intersects) > -1) && !coin1Hover) {
        coin1Hover = true;
        
        var start = {}
        start.y = 0;
        var targ = {};
        targ.y = 0;
        function rot(s,t) {
            start["y"] = s;
            targ["y"] = t;
        }  
        rot(Math.PI/2, 1.5*Math.PI/2);
        const spinning1 = new TWEEN.Tween(start).to(targ, 150).onUpdate(function() {minicylinder1.rotation.y = start.y});
        spinning1.start();

        return coin1Hover    
    } else if ((getIndexInIntersectsArray(minicylinder1, intersects) == -1) && coin1Hover) {
        coin1Hover = false;

        var start = {}
        start.y = 0;
        var targ = {};
        targ.y = 0;
        function rot(s,t) {
            start["y"] = s;
            targ["y"] = t;
        }  
        rot(1.5*Math.PI/2, Math.PI/2);
        const backwards = new TWEEN.Tween(start).to(targ, 450).onUpdate(function() {minicylinder1.rotation.y = start.y});
        backwards.start();

        return coin1Hover
    } else if ((getIndexInIntersectsArray(minicylinder2, intersects) > -1) && !coin2Hover) {
        coin2Hover = true;

        var start = {}
        start.y = 0;
        var targ = {};
        targ.y = 0;
        function rot(s,t) {
            start["y"] = s;
            targ["y"] = t;
        }  
        rot(Math.PI/2, 1.2*Math.PI/2);
        const spinning = new TWEEN.Tween(start).to(targ, 150).onUpdate(function() {minicylinder2.rotation.y = start.y});
        spinning.start();

        return coin2Hover
    } else if ((getIndexInIntersectsArray(minicylinder2, intersects) == -1) && coin2Hover) {
        coin2Hover = false;

        var start = {}
        start.y = 0;
        var targ = {};
        targ.y = 0;
        function rot(s,t) {
            start["y"] = s;
            targ["y"] = t;
        }  
        rot(1.2*Math.PI/2, Math.PI/2);
        const backwards = new TWEEN.Tween(start).to(targ, 450).onUpdate(function() {minicylinder2.rotation.y = start.y});
        backwards.start();

        return coin2Hover
    }
    
    function getIndexInIntersectsArray(elem, array) {
        var ind = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].object.name == elem.name) {
                ind = i;
            }
        }
        return ind;
    }
}
```

I assume it has something to do with the events not finding their way to the second function since the mouse clicks ARE triggering the function in main.js

Thank you so much to anyone that can offer some assistance.